# add column during mysql select

Tags: mysql

I'd like to add a column to the results of a MySql select statement. For instance, if I have a table:

```
|id||name||last_name|
```

Then when I do a select I'd like it to return:

```
|id||name||last_name||some_value|
```

where I specify |some_value| at query time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
id, name,last_name, 1 AS some_value
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

If you want to just hard code a value you can do this:

```
SELECT id, name, last_name, 'value' AS some_value
FROM table
```

Or you can aggregate or modify existing data in the table like this:

```
SELECT id, name, last_name, CONCAT(name, ' ', lastname) AS some_value
FROM table
```